# On infinite permutations of a countable set acting on a set: Does a transposition always witness inequality?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, infinite-groups

Let $\phi \in Sym(\mathbb{N})$, where $\mathbb{N}$ is a set of countable atoms which can be represented by natural numbers and $Sym(\mathbb{N})$ is the symmetric group of $\mathbb{N}$. Let $X$ be a set from a von Neumann-like hierarchy built from these atoms instead of the empty set (like in permutation models of ZFA-- this can be found in Jech's book "The Axiom of Choice"). Let $Sym(\mathbb{N})$ act on such sets with the natural action (moving the atoms). If $\phi X \not= X$, does this imply that there exists a transposition $(a b) \in Sym(\mathbb{N})$ such that $(a b) X \not= X$?

In other words, is it the case that if $X$ is changed upon action by a permutation (moving possibly infinite atoms),  then we can always find a permutation moving only finitely many atoms which changes it?

Comment: This seems obvious with the contrapositive. If $(ab) X = X$ then $X$ contains either both or neither of $a$ and $b$. There aren't very many choices of $X$ if this holds for every $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: In any case, your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Thanks for your response :) I meant that X is from a von Neumenn-like hierarchy built from ℕ (instead of the empty set). I am trying to see in this case if it is possible that X is invariant upon actions moving any finite points but there exits some permutation moving infinite points which leaves it invariant somehow.

Comment: I meant a countable set of atoms like in permutation models of ZFA, where the permutations are on the non-pure sets (as actions on the pure sets are trivial as you mentioned). These are as described in Jech's book "The Axiom of Choice". Sorry I phrased it in this way first (I wanted it to be able to be answered by someone even if they didn't know ZFA theory)

Comment: @LisaT Those last two comments should not be comments, they should be included in the question. If you edit the question accordingly then it will probably be reopened. (I have already voted to reopen, because I can see now that it was a good question.)

Comment: @DerekHolt even with the clarification it is still an isolated problem.

Comment: @ronno Possibly, but for anyone with any expertise in the area it s a sensible question that does not require any further motivation, and I cannot see any genuine reason why the question, together with its answer, should remain closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  For instance, let $E\subset\mathbb{N}$ be the even numbers and let $X$ be the set of subsets $A\subset\mathbb{N}$ such that all but finitely many elements of $A$ are contained in $E$.  Then $\phi X\neq X$ if $\phi$ is a permutation that swaps the even numbers and the odd numbers.  However, $X$ is fixed by any finite-support permutation.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This is exactly the type of counterexample I was trying to construct!